# Uploading files to different disks/directories on server with PHP

Tags: php, upload, disk

I have a server with 2 disks. I want to upload files with PHP and let PHP dynamically choose a `upload_tmp_dir` directory on a disk where the file will be uploaded, either based on disk space or randomly, to reduce amount of IO per disk.

For example: if 5 file uploads are happening at the same time, PHP choose disk1 for upload 1 and 2, and disk2 for upload 3, 4, 5. Is that possible?

As I understand it: during upload, the file gets temporarily stored in the `upload_tmp_dir` directory. And after upload, file can be transferred to some other directory with `move_uploaded_file`.

But I want to let PHP first to check disk space of both disks, compare, and then proceed with uploading the file into the chosen disk - or choose a disk randomly. Is that possible? I have not seen PHP solutions like this.. But i want to keep disk IO to a minimum and utilize my disks as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use `disk_free_space` to check available disk space.
2. Once you compare based on `path` from 1), you already know which disk has more spaces
3. Based on that, you can use `ini_set("upload_tmp_dir", path)` to store tmp file.
4. then you can use `move_uploaded_file` to store the file.

Comment: Thanks I will try that! But is that possible to set `upload_tmp_dir` in a script during runtime? Because `upload_tmp_dir` is in mode `PHP_INI_SYSTEM`, and can only be changed in php.ini or httpd.conf ? https://secure.php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.modes.php

Comment: I have tried it: i have tried to set another upload_tmp_dir during runtime with: `ini_set('upload_tmp_dir', $uploads_dir."/tmp");` and checked if it changed with `sys_get_temp_dir()`, but it did not. tmp dir remains to be the default `/tmp`.

Comment: I checked the `upload_tmp_dir` now with `ini_get` and this time it returns the value that is set with `ini_set`.. so ini_get seems to work..

Comment: My bad on `ini_set`. For 3) you may try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/5864982 @Nemdr